# Conditionally Show/Hide/Disable Custom Workflow Action Buttons

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, custom-actions

I have three custom action buttons on a list created through SharePoint Designer. All three buttons execute a workflow and I need to show/hide or enable/disable the buttons based on certain conditions (e.g. workflow has been executed already, or a value in a column).

[edit, taken from comments]
As far as I know it can't be done in SPD, so I'm looking for some code written with Visual Studio to change the behaviour of these buttons. [/edit]

Can someone please provide me with some guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen things like that build with SP-Designer? Because when you open your Custom-Action, all you can link to a form, link to a workflow or navigate to an url. Other options are button image, Rights mask & a sequence number.
From my point of view I would say: Your only chance is to build a form with Infopath and put there some logic that decides visibility and starts your workflow. But I'm no expert in this, I would do it Visual Studio and JavaScript. And I would wonder if this is possible.

Comment: I know that can not be done with SP-Designer. What I'm wondering is if there is a way to modify the behaviour after-the-fact. So,the button was created with SharePoint Designer, but maybe there is a way to write code that manipulates the button in VS?

Comment: Ah, okay, I didn't read that out from your question. You should edit it to what you wrote here in comment. Well, as far as I experienced, it would be quite challenging. Why? Because When I build something using VS, I was not able to see anything using SPD. The other way round I have no idea how to find out the IDs of SPD-elements. E.g., all SPD-Workflows ends up in WrkFl.aspx or something like that.